# Map ViewModel to IdentityUser

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-identity

I have some additional fields on my User Class for Asp.Net Identity:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{   
    public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel for users:

```
  public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Website { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my mapping:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId));
```

It fails when I try to save a new user, saying Id can't be null:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(UserViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {           
                var user = Mapper.Map<User>(model);
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        }
```

How do I correctly map the Id field?

Comment: The mapping for the id looks correct. You can verify by examining `user.Id` before you attempt to create it. Look at the exception again to be sure it's the `User.Id` that throws the error and not from a missing child collection.

Comment: If I quick view it and click on the base class and then the base class again it is indeed null. It then throws an EntityValidationError: Id is required.

Comment: But AutoMapper did its part? If you create a new User and map out the properties yourself without AutoMapper do you get the same error?

Comment: @Jansen AutoMapper was doing its part - and that was the problem :) When creating a new user I shouldn't be mapping the Id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've been a bit of an idiot - I obviously shouldn't map Id when mapping the UserViewModel to the User as it will be auto generated.

All I did to fix the issue was remove `.ForMember` from the code.

When mapping the other way around - loading a user from the database and displaying it in a View the following code did work correctly for mapping:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```